# How to remove outliers for variable versus another variable in imported dataset in R?

Tags: r, atomic, boxplot, outliers, dollar-sign

I was asked to make boxplot of variable SAW for the 2 surgical intervention types defined by HSW and dataset name is mydata, Then i was asked to check if there any outliers in the boxplot and i found outliers but i can't remove them and i tried multiple ways but all goes with failure.
could you please help me with that issue?

and that is my boxplot

```
boxplot(mydata$SAW~mydata$HSW,main="SAW for two surgical")



no_outliers <- subset(mydata, mydata$SAW > (Q1 - 1.5*IQR) & mydata$HSW < (Q3 + 1.5*IQR))
```

This was my last trial but it gave me error says

```
Error in surgery$SAW : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: (1) While legal, I recommend never using `$`-referencing inside a `~`-formula; instead, use something akin to `boxplot(SAW ~ HSW, data = mydata, ...)`. (2) Similarly, inside `subset(mydata, ...)`, do not use `mydata$`; R will allow it and generally do what you want, but in similar scenarios it will fail or corrupt your data. (3) Do you define `Q1`, `Q3`, and `IQR` somewhere? (4) Note that if you do `bp <- boxplot(...)`, you can see that `bp` has many things available, including `out`liers; see [`?boxplot`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/boxplot.html).

Answer (score 0):

On way would be to use the boxplot object itself-

```
old <- boxplot(disp~am,mtcars)
 # old$out has the outlier values stored
 # filter the df using those values
new <- mtcars[!mtcars$disp %in% old$out,]
## new boxplot withut ouliers..
boxplot(disp~am,new)

#also 
rstatix::identify_outliers()
```